# "No route matches" with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've got a controller test set running where three of the tests succeed and three fail with the same type of error.

For the tests for the `edit`, `update`, and `destroy` actions, I get the associated error saying `No route matches {:controller=>"accounts", action=>"edit"}`

**accounts_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe AccountsController do
before(:each) do
  @account_code = FactoryGirl.create(:account)
end

describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    get 'index'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end

describe "GET 'new'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    get 'new'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end

describe "POST 'create'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    post 'create'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end

describe "GET 'edit'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    get 'edit'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end

describe "POST 'update'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    post 'update'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end

describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    post 'destroy'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
end
```

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    if @account.save
      flash[:success] = "Account created"
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
      flash[:success] = "Account Updated"
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @account.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Account Deleted"
    redirect_to accounts_path
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :account_codes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two errors here

- you do not use the correct verbs for destroy and update, you should use 'delete' for destroy and 'put' for update
- you do not provide an 'id' for these actions, you should use `get :edit, id: 1` , `put :update, id: 1` ...

try running rake routes to see your exact routes

PS: I think you would get the same error for a `show` action as well. If you do not need that action, pass it in as `except: :show` in your resources on routes.rb

Comment: Hinting that we must pass the id parameter for the route to match was the missing part for me.